# How can we use Deduction theorem from A-B=A to A∩B=Ø

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

Question:What can you say about the sets of A and B if we know $A-B=A$?

It is obvious that A minus the empty set to get itself or A is the empty set.

No matter A is the empty set or B is the empty set,we get the conclusion that A∩B=Ø.

However,i don't know how get the the conclusion by Deduction theorem.

$1.∀x((x∈A ∧ x∉B) → x∈A)---premise$

$2.∀x(x∈A → (x∈A ∧ x∉B) )---premise$

$3.x∈A ---premise$

$4.x∈A ∧ x∉B(2,3 Modus ponens)$

$5.x∉B (simplification) $

$6.∀x(x∈A →x∉B)(conditon prove+Universal generation)$

We can get $A⊄B$ but it is not sufficient to show that A∩B=Ø.

As A∩B=Ø,how can we get $∀x(x∈A∧x∈B →x∈Ø)$ in the final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

In a nutshell, the proof assume that $x \in A \cap B$, to conclude that $A \cap B$ is empty.

If $x \in A \cap B$, then $x \in A$ **and** $x \in B$.

From $x \in A$, as per your steps 1-4 : $x \in A$ **and** $x \notin B$: *contradiction* !

Thus:

> $\lnot (x \in A \cap B)$

Now "generalize": $\forall x \lnot (x \in A \cap B)$.

---

Alternatively, having proved: $\lnot (x \in A \cap B)$, we can use the tautology (see [Ex Falso Quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion#Symbolic_representation)): $\lnot P \to (P \to Q)$ to derive (by *Modus Ponens*):

> $(x \in A \cap B) \to (x \in \emptyset)$.

Comment: But  why Q is  (x∈∅), or Q can be any statement?

Comment: @MolyHoly. The tautology is true for any statement Q (whatever Q stands for). So, in particular, it is true when " x belongs to the empty set" is substituted for Q.

Comment: @RayLittleRock but what if i use ¬P→(P→P) to get (x∈A∩B)→(x∈A∩B),or it is just meaningless?

Comment: You may begin by stating clearly what is substituted for what. Here: what is substtuted for P, what for not-P.  Make sure your substitutions are consistent.  What is your substitutuion if your antecedent turns out to be : " x belongs to A Inter B"?

Comment: @MolyHoly - $Q$ can be a formula whatever.

Comment: @MolyHoly - YES. $(P \to P)$ is a tautology, i.e. always True. Thus, also $Q \to (P \to P)$ is, and thus also $\lnot P \to (P \to P)$.

Answer (score 1):

The following proof makes use ( 3 times) of the " conditional proof rule" that is grounded in the deduction principle.

The conditional proof rule says : "Assume H. Derive consequence C under assumption H. Infer (H --> C)".

The proof  also makes use of the " principle of explosion" : from a contradiction, anything follows.

[image]